# How to relate setter buttons with equations

Tags: manipulate

I want to relate or connect a setter bar with a set of equations to graph them.

```
y1[x_] := f'[list[[1]]]*{x - list[[1]]} + f[list[[1]]]
y2[x_] := f'[list[[2]]]*{x - list[[2]]} + f[list[[2]]]
y3[x_] := f'[list[[3]]]*{x - list[[3]]} + f[list[[3]]]
y4[x_] := f'[list[[4]]]*{x - list[[4]]} + f[list[[4]]]
y5[x_] := f'[list[[5]]]*{x - list[[5]]} + f[list[[5]]]

Manipulate[
  Plot[{f[x], y1[x], y2[x], y3[x], y4[x], y5[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
    PlotRange -> 10],
  {{aprox, y1, "Aproximation"}, {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5}, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 list = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {5}]
 f[x_] := x^3;

 y1[x_] := f'[list[[1]]]*{x - list[[1]]} + f[list[[1]]]
 y2[x_] := f'[list[[2]]]*{x - list[[2]]} + f[list[[2]]]
 y3[x_] := f'[list[[3]]]*{x - list[[3]]} + f[list[[3]]]
 y4[x_] := f'[list[[4]]]*{x - list[[4]]} + f[list[[4]]]
 y5[x_] := f'[list[[5]]]*{x - list[[5]]} + f[list[[5]]]

 Manipulate[ Plot[{f[x], aprox[x]}, {x, -3, 3},  PlotRange -> 10], 
 {{aprox, y1, "Aproximation"}, {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5}, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]